# How to get hidden element Height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hidden element in my webpage, I need to get height of that element. I have tried with .clientHeight, offsetHeight, .height(), and window.getComputedStyle but non of this working in attached scenario. Is there any trick to get height without adding any plugin. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teeFD/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="frame">
<p>some text some text some text some text</p>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('p').height()
```

Comment: Try `.clientHeight` instead of `.clientWidth` :p

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: it is my typo error, clientHeight also not working

Comment: You could temporarily remove `display:none` and add `visibility:hidden`.

Comment: alert($('p').html().length)

Comment: @RobertRozas: That won't work... it returns 39 when the actual element height is 20.

Answer (score 2):

You could render it off-screen where the user can't see it, get its height, then restore the element back to normal.

It's better than using `visibility: visible` because it doesn't disrupt the positioning of the other elements on the page.

---

HTML

```html
<div class="frame">
    <p>some text some text some text some text</p>
</div>
```

---

CSS

```css
.frame {
    width: 120px;
    display: none;
}

.offscreen {
    position: fixed !important;
    left: -9999px !important;
    display: inline !important;
}
```

---

JavaScript

```js
$('.frame').addClass('offscreen');

alert('The hieght of \'p\' is: ' + $('p').height() + 'px');

$('.frame').removeClass('offscreen');
```

---

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/HfyfX/

Answer (score 1):

```
var p = $('.frame p').clone().css('display', 'none');
$('body').append(p);
alert(p.height()); // 19
p.remove();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/D9PyE/

Comment: Cloning it is actually a great idea. That way, you don't have to disrupt the original element, no matter how it's set up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/teeFD/5/)

```
alert($('div').removeClass('frame').css('visibility','hidden').find('p').height());
$('div').addClass('frame').css('visibility','visible');
```

You can try this if you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/teeFD/7/

**CSS:-**

```
.frame { width:120px; visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: I don't like that method. It disrupts the other elements' positions ([example here](http://jsfiddle.net/K5rre/1/))

Comment: @JoeSimmons Just add `position:absolute`, it will not affect other elements.

Comment: I like my method better.

Answer (score 0):

For get the height of hidden element you need to set CSS it :

```
$(".frame").css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'visibility': 'hidden', 'display': 'block' });
```

and after getting the height of element again set css:

```
$(".frame").css({'position':'static','visibility':'visible', 'display':'none'});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/teeFD/8/)

```
$(".frame").css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'visibility': 'hidden', 'display': 'block' });
alert($('p').height());
$(".frame").css({'position':'static','visibility':'visible', 'display':'none'});
```